# Getting Live ID to work via WIF

Tags: wif, windows-live-id

I'm attempting to use WIF to have my ASP.NET MVC app rely on Windows Live ID for authentication. I've followed this example exercise:

[Exercise 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/IdentityTrainingCourse/WebSitesAndIdentity/WebSitesAndIdentityLab/Exercise-4-Accepting-Tokens-from-Live-ID)

However, it does not work for me. Mileage varies, sometimes I get an error about Windows Live ID experiencing problems, but most of the time it simply does not redirect back.

Has anyone got WIF and Live ID to cooperate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you download the latest bits from the Training Kit just in case. One of the easiest ways of integrating with LiveID is through Windows Azure AppFabric ACS (Access Control Service). In addition to LiveID it gives you integration with other Identity Providers (Google, Facebook, any WS-Federation STS, etc).