# Implementing MembershipProvider

Tags: ria, membership-provider

I'd like to use Microsoft Live/Connect/Passport (did I miss anyone?) identities with Silverlight/RIA.

This has a number of advantages:

- Avoids foisting yet another username/password pair on people
- User account management is wholly delegated to Passport and forms no part of my application or its UI
- Responsibility for security and availability is removed to the company that everyone loves to hate

Now, RIA uses the membership stack from ASP.NET, which by default backs onto aspnetdb in SQL Server.

I'm looking into implementing MembershipProvider. So far I've set up appropriate references and overridden MembershipProvider, letting the IDE stub all the methods that need implementation.

I've set EnablePasswordReset and EnablePasswordRetrieval to return false, because my app does not provide these services. ValidateUser(username, password) is implemented and working, using WebClient to delegate the check to Microsoft's servers. Yet vast hordes of methods remain, all threatening NotImplementedException, and I have no idea which ones RIA might call. This leads me to...

### The question

Does anyone know how much of MembershipProvider I actually need to implement, given that user account management is wholly delegated to Passport?

It crosses my mind that even though authentication and account management are delegated, it may be prudent to cache credentials. Once an identity is established, it would be preferable if it could be used in the absence of an internet connection. For example, you can still use your Passport credentials to log onto a Surface RT when it doesn't have an internet connection.

Perhaps I should inherit from SqlMembershipProvider, so that ValidateUser checks whether a username is locally known, and if not tries the credentials with Passport and - if they pass - implicitly creates the local user, and if it does exist but the credentials fail, checks with passport in case the local password is stale, updating it if Passport accepts the password.

If you like the idea, your input is solicited.

Answer (score 0):

With the Custom MembershipProvider, you only need to implement,

- GetUser
- ValidateUser

Another thought, with LiveID, it supports Security Token Service, so you can use Windows Identity Framework see here 
[Getting Live ID to work via WIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674762/getting-live-id-to-work-via-wif)

Comment: Looked like *such* a good idea, but the learning curve and the dependencies are nightmarish. It would be worthwhile if you were already developing an Azure app.